# Tikz Draw on Digraph without repeating each arc command with [->]?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

The graph of Case 1 is the correct but repeating statements for arcs. In comparison, Case 2 is easier and faster to write without repeating the arcs statements. I have a feeling that there must be a style command or similar to avoid repeating the command and that specifies that each edge is directed to some direction. So

**How to draw arcs with Tikz Draw without repeating each arc command with [->]?**

*1. Case: goal like this with all edges directed*

> [image]
>
> ```
> \draw[->] (Input)--(1);
> \draw[->] (1)--(2);
> \draw[->] (2)--(Output);
> \draw[->] (Input)--(3);
> \draw[->] (3)--(4);
> \draw[->] (4)--(Output);
> \draw[->] (Input)--(5);
> \draw[->] (5)--(7);
> \draw[->] (7)--(Output);
> \draw[->] (Input)--(6);
> \draw[->] (6)--(7);
> ```

*2. Not like this where some edges not directed*

> [image]
>
> ```
> \draw[->] (Input)--(1)--(2)--(Output);
> \draw[->] (Input)--(3)--(4)--(Output);
> \draw[->] (Input)--(5)--(7)--(Output);
> \draw[->] (Input)--(6)--(7)--(Output);
> ```

Comment: An arrow is added by `->` at the end of a path, which is the reason why point 2 does not have all the arrows. For point 1 have you tried to set `->` as an option of the surrounding `tikzpicture` or `scope`? Maybe what you are really looking for is the `edge` operation instead of `--`

Comment: Could you please post a MWE with some nodes declared so it is compilable?

Comment: @Bordaigorl Thank you, MWEs [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312851/2956) with comparison between the repeating solution and the less repeating alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Point 1: avoiding repeating `->`

You can set the option globally (or using a scope)

```
% \usetikzlibrary{automata} for `state` key
\begin{tikzpicture}[->]

\foreach[count=\i] \n in {A,B,C,D,E}{
    \node[state] at (\i*60:1+rnd*3)  (\n) {\n};
}

\draw (A)--(B);
\draw (B)--(C);
\draw (C)--(D);
\draw (A)--(E);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

#### Point 2: drawing arrows in a single path

You can use the `edge` action:

```
\draw[->] (A) edge (B)
          (B) edge (C)
          (C) edge (D)
          (A) edge (E);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Bordaigorl's suggestion with edge command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312844/2956) solves the issue. I provide the MWEs below. For me, the MWEs compile identical where the latter solution is better with less repeating

[image]

**Bad repeating solution**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm, y=2cm,scale=0.8]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw, circle, fill=white, inner sep=3pt,minimum size=18pt] 

\draw (0,0) node[minimum size=1.5cm](Output){Sink};
\draw (0,-3) node[minimum size=1.5cm](Input){Source};

\draw (-1,-1) node(1){1};
\draw (0,-1) node(3){3};
\draw (0.5,-1) node(5){5};
\draw (1.5,-1) node(6){6};
\draw (-1,-2) node(2){2};
\draw (0,-2) node(4){4};
\draw (1,-2) node(7){7};

\draw[->] (1)--(Output);
\draw[->] (3)--(Output);
\draw[->] (5)--(Output);
\draw[->] (6)--(Output);
\draw[->] (2)--(1);
\draw[->] (4)--(3);
\draw[->] (7)--(5);
\draw[->] (7)--(6);
\draw[->] (Input)--(2);
\draw[->] (Input)--(4);
\draw[->] (Input)--(7);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

**Better less repeating solution**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm, y=2cm,scale=0.8]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw, circle, fill=white, inner sep=3pt,minimum size=18pt] 

\draw (0,0) node[minimum size=1.5cm](Output){Sink};
\draw (0,-3) node[minimum size=1.5cm](Input){Source};

\draw (-1,-1) node(1){1};
\draw (0,-1) node(3){3};
\draw (0.5,-1) node(5){5};
\draw (1.5,-1) node(6){6};
\draw (-1,-2) node(2){2};
\draw (0,-2) node(4){4};
\draw (1,-2) node(7){7};

\draw[->] (Input) edge (2) 
          (2) edge (1) 
          (1) edge (Output);
\draw[->] (Input) edge (4) 
          (4) edge (3) 
         (3) edge (Output);
\draw[->] (Input) edge (7) 
          (7) edge (5) 
          (5) edge (Output);
\draw[->] (7) edge (6) 
          (6) edge (Output);

\end{tikzpicture}
```